# Rails 3: Class method not found in validates statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following class in a Rails 3 app:

```
class Attribute
  ...
  def self.ANNOTATION
    self.find_by_table_name('annotations')
  end
  ...
end
```

In another class, I refer to this method in a `validates` call:

```
validates :attribute_type_id, :attr_correct => {attr: Attribute.ANNOTATION}
```

When I run my tests, I get a NoMethodError for `Attribute.ANNOTATION`. However, if I just refer to `Attribute.ANNOTATION` in the `AttrCorrectValidator.validate_each` method, it works just fine.

Why wouldn't my class method be recognized in the `validates` statement? Could it have something to do with how class declarations are evaluated by Ruby/Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name collision.  The full messages is

```
undefined method `ANNOTATION' for ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Serialization::Attribute:Class
```

So you are defining a class, but Ruby is finding another one by the same name, which doesn't have ANNOTATION defined.

Possible fixes: fully qualify on each problematic use (i.e. `::Attribute.ANNOTATION`) or rename the class.

Comment: Should've known. Thanks! As an aside, I haven't seen the fully-qualified syntax before. Is there an implied class before the `::`, like `Object::Attribute.ANNOTATION` or is this its own thing?

Comment: `::`, when used as a unary operator, will resolve to operand using the global (anonymous) namespace.